# Can I create multiple communities within the same Buddypress installation?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have been away from the Buddypress world for a while. I am currently trying to re-learn it. I am trying to build a site that will host three communities. Each community will have three types of users. Should I use the "groups" feature to create the three communities? If so, how would I create the three types of users? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about using multisite? http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: @henrywright The site admin should be able add an user to multiple groups and communities.  Is multi-site a good solution for that?

Comment: In multisite, you would have a network admin account that manages all sites within the network. The network admin can manage users across all sites in the network.

Comment: @henrywright Can the user easily jump from one community(site) to another?

Comment: Have you ever used wordpress.com? That's basically multisite in action. If you sign up as a user, you'll see what you can and can't do. But to answer your question "Can the user easily jump from one community(site) to another" - No. They would have to register on each site.